# How to use Style's FontVariations "Shadow" option value

Tags: output-formatting, style

`FontVariations` is an option for `Style` that has a `"Shadow"` option value.  However, using `"Shadow"` does not produce a shadow around the characters as stated in the documentation.

```
Style["123 abc", FontVariations -> {"Shadow" -> True}]
```

How do I get this option to work? Also, is it possible to set the colour of the shadow with this option? For example, black text and red shadow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of these things are OS specific. This is V11 on OS X 10.11

[image]